# Import jars to project classpath from a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two projects:

**Project A** the main project which is not a maven project, depending from
**Project B** which is a maven project.

I need to import the **Project B** jar and all his dependencies to **project A** classpath, the problem is I have to import all jars manually one by one from my m2 repo. Is there a way to import those jars at once?

Comment: You can try creating a "fat jar" of project B. https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Maven Assembly Plugin` in B to build a jar with dependencies.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mkyong.core.utils.App</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```